# How to avoid adding the same navbar template to every .html page

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at the scene and I'm using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [this template](http://startbootstrap.com/sb-admin) for the first time. I need help with the navbar. In the template each `content.html` has their own navbar.

I need the navbar in a separate file, because I do not want to make changes in every single `content.html` file.

In my old site without Bootstrap I worked with:

```
<?php
include("includes/navigation.html");
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Isn't the include working? You should only need to put navbar's div inside the include file.

Comment: You still can cut/paste the navbar HTML code into an other file and include it with PHP.

Comment: You could still use the include method. All you are changing is the content of navigation.html and the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need configure to put your repeated html data's in a single file and include that one into another.

Lets simple,

if your Project structure like this

- project(folder)

  - db(folder)

    - Dbconnection.php(file)
  - js(folder)

    - jquery.js(file)
  - css(folder)

    - bootstrap.css(file)
  - index.php(file)
  - page1.php(file)
  - page2.php(file)

Create a new file with contents of your `navbar` html tags alone.

For ex. in your `nav-menu.php` contains

```
<navbar>
    ......
    ......
</navbar>
```

and save them into new `includes` folder in your project. So now your project structure will be like this one,

- project(folder)

  - db(folder)

    - Dbconnection.php(file)
  - js(folder)

    - jquery.js(file)
  - css(folder)

    - bootstrap.css(file)
  - includes(folder)

    - nav-menu.php(file)
  - index.php(file)
  - page1.php(file)
  - page2.php(file)

Now you should include this file(`nav-menu.php`) in all the template files using php `include` method, like

```
include("includes/nav-menu.php");
```

Add this above code in all of your common files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<?php include("includes/navigation.php") ?>
```

in this project too.

Fastest way that comes to my mind is to just include the code you need to change for every page in a separate switch/case and call the different cases at the top of the page that is including the navbar.

Just note your navigation file needs to be .php, not .html like your example.