# Bootstrap scrollspy with separate navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help with Bootstrap Scrollspy. I have this [project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162450/how-to-avoid-adding-the-same-navbar-template-to-every-html-page) and this is [the template](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin/index.html) I use. U can see that i have different content php's and one navigation.

I have read the official guide and this example, but how can I link the pages with the navigation? Dont get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollspy uses href link attributes in navigation, to spy title ids while scrolling.